# How to reuse or expand .env variable in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, environment-variables

I have reactJS APP(CRA) and added .env file for properties.But every time I need to type the same value in multiple places. So is there any way to reuse it.

my `.env`:

```
REACT_APP_SERVER_API=https://api.mysite.com
REACT_APP_AUTH_API=https://api.mysite.com/auth/login
...
```

but want something like

```
REACT_APP_AUTH_API=${REACT_APP_SERVER_API}/auth/login
```

I tried different way like:

```
REACT_APP_AUTH_API=${REACT_APP_SERVER_API}
REACT_APP_AUTH_API={REACT_APP_SERVER_API}
REACT_APP_AUTH_API=REACT_APP_SERVER_API
REACT_APP_AUTH_API=`${REACT_APP_SERVER_API}`
REACT_APP_AUTH_API=`{REACT_APP_SERVER_API}`
```

none the above is evaluated so I am forced to type same thing multiple times, I have huge list of api having parent-child uri.

Comment: If your url schema doesnt change, but only the host, surely you only need to store REACT_APP_SERVER_API in env. You could then create a config object that inludes REACT_APP_SERVER_API, for instance ```const urls = {loginAPI:`${REACT_APP_SERVER_API}/auth/login`}```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in create-react-app docs [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#expanding-environment-variables-in-env).

Expand variables local to the current .env file:

```
DOMAIN=www.example.com
REACT_APP_FOO=$DOMAIN/foo
REACT_APP_BAR=$DOMAIN/bar
```

Alternatively, you can handle this in javascript file.

```
const API_BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_API;

const LOGIN_URL = `${API_BASE_URL}/auth/login`;
const GET_DATA = `${API_BASE_URL}/data`;
```

Comment: the above is not evaluating properly,

this is in .env:
DOMAIN=www.example.com
REACT_APP_FOO=$DOMAIN/foo
REACT_APP_BAR=$DOMAIN/bar
but it showing as:
REACT_APP_FOO: "$DOMAIN/foo"
REACT_APP_BAR: "$DOMAIN/bar"

Comment: I've tested this on my local system and it is working as expected. Maybe try updating the `react-scripts` version to latest. Also try creating a new CRA project on local and test the same thing.

Comment: this is the version using:---
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",

Comment: I just changed to dotenv insteadof env-cmd and it worked....Thanks